# Monaco Editor: how to know when the code suggestion provider is ready

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using monaco editor for a project, and providing a JSON schema to the editor to do autocompletion and validation of the JSON code I enter in the editor.

I've also added some tests for checking if the code suggestion provider works as intended and I'm observing flaky behaviour there.

Sometimes, the autosuggestion provider is not ready by the time test runs and I don't get any automatic suggestions on typing.

Rest of the times it works as expected.

Question: Is there a callback which can we used to know that the schema suggestions are consumed and the suggestion provider is now ready?